# PHP prepared statement issue

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I am getting Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 3 by reference in line# 4
please suggest me solution I want the binding part dynamic.

```
$values = array($username,$password);
$query = "select * from users where email_id = ? and password = ?"
$this->con = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password','dbname');
$stmt = $this->con->prepare($query);
$count = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++) {
    $stmt->bind_param(++$count,$values[$i], PDO::PARAM_STR,12);
}
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    while ($row = $this->stmt->fetch()) {
       $data[] = $row;
    }
    return $data;
} else {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should also include what is in `$query`? Also, what have you tried so far to fix this problem?

Comment: @Styphon i have added all the information you need.please suggest now.

Comment: I'm suggesting that you learn how to read documentation about PHP functions. The documentation **clearly** says that parameter 3 is **reference**. You are sending an **INTEGER VALUE**, it's not a **VARIABLE**. These are basics, what you must and should do is learn how to use PHP rather than ask these questions on SO.

Answer (score 1):

use bindValue()

```
$stmt->bindValue(++$count,$values[$i], PDO::PARAM_STR,12);
```